# Wordpress site doesn't work in localhost running in android emulator

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, wamp

I just want to learn how to build responsive themes and I installed the android emulator on win7 and all is ok when I test sites which are running on a live server. The problem is that is not working when I try to test wordpress sites from WAMP server. I'm using 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost or ip... It's working for simple html files but not for wp. It shows me a sitemap with all the site pages and when I try to click on one of them it shows me an error "The webpage might be temporarily down...".
I need to test them on WAMP server before uploading them on a live server. What should I do?... When I uplaod them on server, (the same theme), all is working. Could be something wrong with the wamp configuration?. I test it on 2 pc's (32 and 64) and the same is happening.

I found http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZR6E9I0PKoI video and there I see that it's working for him. What am I missing.

Thanks for your help,

Florin

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
I tested the instructions on the video and they worked fine; I was using WordPress multisite and didn't work, so I created a standalone setup and it worked :)

Here's a simple solution I tested and working for debugging WordPress themes on Android.

1. First you have to be able to access your localhost from your mobile, follow this instructions [here](http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/).
2. Now you should be able to access your localhost from Android. Since WP is redirecting addresss like `http://192.168.0.100/wordpress/` to something like `http://localhost/wordpress/`.  Better create a directory on your www folder and test your html versions of styles until they suite your responsive needs.